# Is there any difference between "She lives on a far-flung land" and "She lives on a far-off land"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-meaning, difference, phrase-choice

The Oxford dictionary says

> [far-off](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/far-off?q=far-off) adjective  /ˈfɑːr ɒf/  /ˈfɑːr ɔːf/ [only before noun] ​a long
> distance away

> [far-flung](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/far-flung?q=far-flung) adjective  /ˌfɑː ˈflʌŋ/  /ˌfɑːr ˈflʌŋ/ [usually before noun]
> (literary) ​a long distance away

So both "**far-flung**" and "**far-off**" mean "**a long distance away**".

Is there any difference between "**She lives on a far-flung land**" and "**She lives on a far-off land**"?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, when 'land' refers to a country, we say that a person lives '*in*' that land, not 'on' it.

To be honest, both 'far-away land' and 'far-flung land' are pretty much interchangeable. I should note that both are very non-specific, and are not likely to be used in a serious piece of writing.
These days, you are more likely to only hear such terms in fantasy fiction. In a serious piece of writing you are more likely to see remote places referred to as "*distant lands*".

There is also something quite dismissive about these terms, and I don't think that people would call a place "a far-flung land" if they could instead just name it. A common phrase that comes to mind is "*the far-flung corners of the earth*", which I suspect comes from the western world as it seems to suggest a starting point from which the rest of the world is measured. It could even be considered offensive to natives of a country to call it such.

Comment: +1 "Far flung corners" even suggests old rectangular maps of the "known world".